# write jsonobject data to xml tags

Tags: java, json, xml, file

I want to read from an xml file to a JSONObject and write it to another xml file.

But I am going wrong somewhere to write JSONObject to xml file in java.

I am using org.json jar file

May I know, where am I going wrong?

Requirement : 
        Write JSONObject to XML file in tags.

My code snippet :

```
public class xmltojson
{
    static String line="",str="";
    public static void main(String[] args) throws JSONException, IOException
    {
        String link = "SOURCE_FILEPATH\\Files.xml";
        BufferedReader br = new BufferedReader(new FileReader(link));
        while ((line = br.readLine()) != null)
        {
           str+=line;
        }

        JSONObject jsondata = XML.toJSONObject(str);

        String xml = XML.toString(jsondata);

        String xmlFile = DESTINATION_FILEPATH\\filefromjson.xml";

        try (FileWriter fileWriter = new FileWriter(xmlFile))
        {
            fileWriter.write(XML.toString(jsondata));
        }
    }
}
```

Current output:

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>

-<Files>

<clsid>{215B2E53-57CE-475c-80FE-9EEC14635851}</clsid>

<disabled>0</disabled>


-<File>

    <clsid>{50BE44C8-567A-4ed1-B1D0-9234FE1F38AF}</clsid>

    <image>0</image>

    <uid>{18348506-E3DE-4C1E-A2DC-B91087376BC4}</uid>

    <name>default.jpeg</name>

    <disabled>0</disabled>


    -<Properties>

        <fromPath>C:\Users\Administrator\Documents\dragon_ball_kai-goku.jpeg</fromPath>

        <hidden>0</hidden>

        <action>C</action>

       <targetPath>C:\Users\Administrator\Downloads\default.jpeg</targetPath>

       <readOnly>0</readOnly>

       <archive>1</archive>

    </Properties>

    <status>default.jpeg</status>

    <changed>2018-08-14 06:36:56</changed>

</File>


....
```

But expected output is :

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>

-<Files disabled="0" clsid="{215B2E53-57CE-475c-80FE-9EEC14635851}">


    -<File disabled="0" clsid="{50BE44C8-567A-4ed1-B1D0-9234FE1F38AF}" uid="{18348506-E3DE-4C1E-A2DC-B91087376BC4}" changed="2018-08-14 06:36:56" image="0" status="default.jpeg" name="default.jpeg">

        <Properties hidden="0" archive="1" readOnly="0" targetPath="C:\Users\Administrator\Downloads\default.jpeg" fromPath="C:\Users\Administrator\Documents\dragon_ball_kai-goku.jpeg" action="C"/>

</File>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

By looking at the documentation of `XML.toJSONObject` method:

> Convert a well-formed (but not necessarily valid) XML string into a JSONObject. **Some information may be lost in this transformation because JSON is a data format and XML is a document format**. XML uses elements, attributes, and content text, while JSON uses unordered collections of name/value pairs and arrays of values. JSON does not does not like to distinguish between **elements and attributes**. Sequences of similar elements are represented as JSONArrays. Content text may be placed in a "content" member. Comments, prologs, DTDs, and <[ [ ]]> are ignored.

Due to such imformation lost, the XML converted back is not equals to original XML.

To solve the problem, use `JSONML.toJSONObject` instead. As the documentation of method:

> Convert a well-formed (but not necessarily valid) XML string into a JSONObject using the JsonML transform. Each XML tag is represented as a JSONObject with a "tagName" property. **If the tag has attributes, then the attributes will be in the JSONObject as properties**. **If the tag contains children, the object will have a "childNodes" property which will be an array of strings and JsonML JSONObjects**. Comments, prologs, DTDs, and <[ [ ]]> are ignored.

This [site](http://www.jsonml.org/xml/) provides more details about JsonML.

Check the following code for the different

```
import org.json.JSONException;
import org.json.JSONML;
import org.json.JSONObject;
import org.json.XML;

public class JsonToXml {
    public static void main(String[] args) throws JSONException {

        String originalXML = "<?xml version=\"1.0\"?><a t=\"tt\"><b><c>1</c><c>2</c></b></a>";
        System.out.println("oringinal XML:" + originalXML);
        JSONObject jsonConvertByXML = XML.toJSONObject(originalXML);
        System.out.println("jsonConvertByXML:" + jsonConvertByXML);

        String xmlConvertedBackByXML = XML.toString(jsonConvertByXML);
        System.out.println("xmlConvertedBackByXML:" + xmlConvertedBackByXML);

        JSONObject jsonConvertByJSONML = JSONML.toJSONObject(originalXML);
        System.out.println(jsonConvertByJSONML);
        String xmlConvertedBackByJSONML = JSONML.toString(jsonConvertByJSONML);
        System.out.println("xmlConvertedBackByJSONML:" + xmlConvertedBackByJSONML);
    }
}
```